# Implementing a function with tensorflow

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, softmax

I am  new to programming, especially programming with tensorflow.  I'm making toy problems to understand using it. 
In that case I want to build a function like softmax, where the denominator is not the sum of all classes, but a sum of some sampled classes.

In python using numpy would be like:

```
def my_softmax(X,W, num_of_samples):
    K = 4
    S = np.zeros(((np.dot(X,np.transpose(W))).shape))
    for line in range(X.shape[0]):
        XW = np.dot(X[line],np.transpose(W))
        m = np.max(XW)
        samples_sum = 0
        for s in range(num_of_samples):
            r = (randint(0,K-1))
            samples_sum += np.exp(XW[r]- m)

        S[line] = (np.exp(XW-m))/(samples_sum)

    return S
```

How could this be implemented in tensorflow? 
More generally, is there a possible way to create new "custom" functions like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap Python/numpy functions as tensorflow operators. See tf.py_func
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/script_ops.html

However, it is better to not use it in production setting as performance will be (significantly) impacted. For most of np.* functions you will find corresponding tf.* functions that you can use. Try to represent all your computation in terms of matrix/vector instead of for loop.

Also see
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/constant_op.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think that you are right and i should try the matrix/vector coding instead of for loop, but as i am new to programming i can't think of a way for doing that. How could i avoid the "for line in range(X.shape[0]):" for example? Because i have to calculate a different denominator with random samples for every line. Confusing!

Comment: Perhaps take a look at: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#sampled_softmax_loss ? Some of the candidate sampling library functions just next to that function in the documentation might help here too. You can look at the source to see how they are implemented.

Comment: @AjayJoshi Your first link https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/script_ops.html is not working. Please update it.